# Vista speech recognition in multiple languages

Tags: windows-vista, language, speech-recognition

my primary language is spanish, but I use all my software in english, including windows; however I'd like to use speech recognition in spanish.

Do you know if there's a way to use vista's speech recognition in other language than the primary os language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could use Spanish if your OS was in Spanish. From MS knowledge base.

**[The Windows Speech Recognition language must be the same as the operating system language in Windows Vista](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934377)**